# Where do I download com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.* package

Tags: java

I follow the steps to use java to connect swift
http://ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/swift/java/#setup
but I can find the packages:

```
import com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.FilesClient;
import com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.FilesConstants;
import com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.FilesContainer;
import com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.FilesContainerExistsException;
import com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.FilesObject;
import com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles.FilesObjectMetaData;
```

where can I get them??

Comment: http://www.findjar.com could be helpful. That's where I go when I have missing jars.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

download this jar [aws-java-sdk-1.1.7.1.jar](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/archive-details/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.1.7.1/aws-java-sdk-1.1.7.1.jar)

there are lot of sites providing to search Class file.

Ex : findjar.com and jarvana.com ...

Comment: you just click on jar in the answer. Go to that page on find download option to download that particular jar.

Comment: I used the website and just find some jcloud packages, but it seems not suit for swift api connect

Comment: The jar file does not seem to be available anymore. Anybody know where to find it? Or more than that, the Maven dependency to download it. I found a few references to com.rackspacecloud in mvnrepository.com but none of those jars contained the com.rackspacecloud.client.cloudfiles package.

Answer (score 0):

The source for that package ([officially referred to as the Rackspace Cloud Files Java API)](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/java-api-installation) is [available on github here](https://github.com/rackerlabs/java-cloudfiles).